# Converting pandas column of comma-separated strings into dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas, split, dummy-variable

In my dataframe, I have a categorical variable that I'd like to convert into dummy variables. This column however has multiple values separated by commas:

```
0    'a'
1    'a,b,c'
2    'a,b,d'
3    'd'
4    'c,d'
```

Ultimately, I'd want to have binary columns for each possible discrete value; in other words, final column count equals number of unique values in the original column. I imagine I'd have to use split() to get each separate value but not sure what to do afterwards. Any hint much appreciated!

Edit: Additional twist. Column has null values. And in response to comment, the following is the desired output. Thanks!

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  0
2  1  1  0  1
3  0  0  0  1
4  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output for the example you've given

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use str.get_dummies

```
df['col'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')

    a   b   c   d
0   1   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   0
2   1   1   0   1
3   0   0   0   1
4   0   0   1   1
```

Edit: Updating the answer to address some questions.

Qn 1: Why is it that the series method get_dummies does not accept the argument prefix=... while pandas.get_dummies() does accept it

[Series.str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) is a series level method (as the name suggests!). We are one hot encoding values in one Series (or a DataFrame column) and hence there is no need to use prefix. [Pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) on the other hand can one hot encode multiple columns. In which case, the prefix parameter works as an identifier of the original column.

If you want to apply prefix to str.get_dummies, you can always use [DataFrame.add_prefix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)

```
df['col'].str.get_dummies(sep=',').add_prefix('col_')
```

Qn 2: If you have more than one column to begin with, how do you merge the dummies back into the original frame?
You can use [DataFrame.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to merge one hot encoded columns with the rest of the columns in dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'other':['x','y','x','x','q'],'col':['a','a,b,c','a,b,d','d','c,d']})
df = pd.concat([df, df['col'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')], axis = 1).drop('col', 1)

  other a   b   c   d
0   x   1   0   0   0
1   y   1   1   1   0
2   x   1   1   0   1
3   x   0   0   0   1
4   q   0   0   1   1
```

Comment: I feel stupid.... but this is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't. Very few know all the functions that are available, rest of us are at different stages of learning :) All the best

Comment: This might be obvious, but if your data is separated by a comma and a space, make sure to include it! That is, `sep = ', '` Otherwise, you end up with duplicate columns.

Comment: why is it that the series method get_dummies does not accept the argument prefix=... while pandas.get_dummies() does accept it?

Comment: This is what i'm also trying to do but due to large data and variability among it, it's giving memory error. Any method to get out of it?

Comment: If you have more than one column to begin with, how do you merge the dummies back into the original frame?

Comment: Great answer, thanks for including the concat portion at the end. Saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 5):

The `str.get_dummies` function does not accept `prefix` parameter, but you can rename the column names of the returned dummy DataFrame:

```
data['col'].str.get_dummies(sep=',').rename(lambda x: 'col_' + x, axis='columns')
```