# Convert categorical data into dummy set

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, dummy-variable

I'm having data like this:-

```
|--------|---------|
| Col1   | Col2    |
|--------|---------|
| X      | a,b,c   |
|--------|---------|
| Y      | a,b     |
|--------|---------|
| X      | b,d     |
|--------|---------|
```

I want to convert these categorical data to dummy variables. Since my data is large its giving memory error if i'm using `get_dummies()` from pandas. I want my result like this:-

```
|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|Col_X |Col_Y |Col2_a|Col2_b|Col2_c|Col2_d|
|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  1   |  0   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  0   |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  0   | 1    |  1   |  1   |  0   |   0  |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|  1   | 0    |  0   |  1   |  0   |   1  |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|
```

I have tried to convert Col2 using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867201/converting-pandas-column-of-comma-separated-strings-into-dummy-variables) but getting MemoryError as data is large and there is lot of variability in col2 too.

So,

1) How can I convert multiple categorical columns into dummy variable?

2) pandas get_dummy() is giving memory error, so how could i handle that?

Comment: You can preprocess the data first. If you are working on ML, you can remove stopwords and apply stemming & lemmatization which should reduce the count of unique words in the data.

Comment: Yes, I need to use this data for ML, but I'm not working on text data. These are some codes in str. @Vaishali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to give my solution as well. And I would like to thank @James-dellinger for the answer. So here is my approach

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['X', 'Y', 'X'],
               'Col2': ['a,b,c', 'a,b', 'b,d']})
df

  Col1  Col2
0   X   a,b,c
1   Y   a,b
2   X   b,d
```

I first split Col2 values and convert it into column values.

```
df= pd.DataFrame(df['Col2'].str.split(',',3).tolist(),columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3'])

df

   Col1 Col2 Col3
0   a   b    c
1   a   b    None
2   b   d    None
```

Then I applied dummy creation on this dataframe without giving any prefix.

```
df=pd.get_dummies(df, prefix="")

df

    _a  _b  _b  _d  _c
0   1   0   1   0   1
1   1   0   1   0   0
2   0   1   0   1   0
```

Now to get the desired result we can sum up all the duplicate columns.

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()

df

    _a  _b  _c  _d
0   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   0   0
2   0   1   0   1
```

For Col1 we can directly create dummy variables using `pd.get_dummies()` and store it into different dataframe suppose `col1_df`. We can concat both columns using `pd.concat([df,col1_df], axis=1, sort=False)`

Comment: I like this approach. I had initially tried something similar, but got stuck when it didn't occur to me that I could leave prefix blank and then group columns by identical suffixes.

Comment: I also want to know that how can I apply this to live input if I deploy a model using this dataset? @JamesDellinger

Comment: I assume you would include the above steps in your pre-processing pipeline, and any new input would be preprocessed accordingly before predictions are made on it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost positive that you're encountering memory issues because [str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas.Series.str.get_dummies) returns an array full of 1s and 0s, of datatype `np.int64`. This is quite different from the behavior of [pd.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas.get_dummies), which returns an array of values of datatype `uint8`.

This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19618). However, there's been no update, nor fix, for the past year. Checking out the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.1/pandas/core/strings.py#L1010) for str.get_dummies will indeed confirm that it is returning `np.int64`.

An 8 bit integer will take up 1 byte of memory, while a 64 bit integer will take up 8 bytes. I'm hopeful that memory problems can be avoided by finding an alternative way to one-hot encode `Col2` which ensures the output are all 8 bit integers.

Here was my approach, beginning with your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['X', 'Y', 'X'],
                   'Col2': ['a,b,c', 'a,b', 'b,d']})
df

    Col1    Col2
0   X       a,b,c
1   Y       a,b
2   X       b,d
```

1. Since `Col1` contains simple, non-delimited strings, we can easily one-hot encode it using pd.get_dummies:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Col1'])
df

    Col2    Col1_X  Col1_Y
0   a,b,c        1       0
1   a,b          0       1
2   b,d          1       0
```

So far so good.

```
df['Col1_X'].values.dtype
dtype('uint8')
```

2. Let's get a list of all unique substrings contained inside the comma-delimited strings in `Col2`:

```
vals = list(df['Col2'].str.split(',').values)
vals = [i for l in vals for i in l]
vals = list(set(vals))
vals.sort()
vals

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

3. Now we can loop through the above list of values and use `str.contains` to create a new column for each value, such as `'a'`. Each row in a new column will contain 1 if that row actually has the new column's value, such as `'a'`, inside its string in `Col2`. As we create each new column, we make sure to convert its datatype to `uint8`:

```
col='Col2'
for v in vals:
    n = col + '_' + v
    df[n] = df[col].str.contains(v)
    df[n] = df[n].astype('uint8')

df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)
df

    Col1_X  Col1_Y  Col2_a  Col2_b  Col2_c  Col2_d
0        1       0       1       1       1       0
1        0       1       1       1       0       0
2        1       0       0       1       0       1
```

This results in a dataframe that meets your desired format. And thankfully, the integers in the four new columns that were one-hot encoded from `Col2` only take up 1 byte each, as opposed to 8 bytes each.

```
df['Col2_a'].dtype
dtype('uint8')
```

If, on the outside chance, the above approach doesn't work. My advice would be to use str.get_dummies to one-hot encode `Col2` in chunks of rows. Each time you do a chunk, you would convert its datatype from `np.int64` to `uint8`, and then [transform the chunk to a sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922487/how-to-transform-numpy-matrix-or-array-to-scipy-sparse-matrix). You could eventually concatenate all chunks back together.

Comment: it's not giving memory error for now. But the process is running for quite long. any thing we can do to speed up the process.

Comment: also its giving `cannot convert float NaN to integer` as some of the rows contain null values as well

Comment: For `Col2`, simply use this: 
df['Col2'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')